# Angular function of class of class

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular (v7).

I get an object A from my Json service and cast it to Class ObjectA.

This ObjectA object itself contains an ObjectB class which also contains an Object3 class.

When I create a get method in my Object3, I can't access it.

It looks like my Object3 is not of type Object3.

Do you have any advice on how to do this work?

Sorry for my english

Thank you

Comment: casting doesn't do anything in typescript besides inform the compiler of the interface. you need to actually construct the object if you want the methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making `http requests` what you get in response is just a `string` which will be parsed into some object using `JSON.parse` method. But this not gonna make you object like you declared you are expecting, so you won't have declared methods or even types (if you declared f.e. field is type of `Moment` it won't parse you to a `Moment` but it will be a string). You have to manually parse this object and "cast" fields to required type (treat response as a DTO). You can use `Object.assign` method and `pipe(map())` the `http.get` method.